# For loop with dictionary and If-Condition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

How can i get a new list of items with a for loop and an if-statement while working with dictionarys?

I have a list with a set of numbers and want to check if these numbers are in my dictionary that i created. The next step is then to create a new list, for every number that is inside the dictionary, with the values from it.

```
import pandas as pd

## Create new list with data inside .csv

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";")

item_nr = df["Items"].tolist()

item_date = df["Date"].tolist()

# Creating a dict with for loop ("Item":"Date")

item_dict = {}

for i in range(len(item_nr)):
    item_dict[item_nr[i]] = item_date[i]

## Creating a list with dates from dictionary

date_list = []

for item in items_list_sold:
    if item == item_dict.keys():
        date_list.append(item_dict)

print(date_list)
```

Comment: You don't have a list, originally, you have a dataframe. Look into [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) first

Comment: I forgot to mention that this code is part of a larger programm, so "items_list_sold" is a list of items which i created at the beginning of the whole programm. So when i run the whole programm there are 6 Item Numbers inside which i want to loop over.

Comment: Second, `if item == item_dict.keys()` will not work because you're comparing to the whole `keys` object. You want `if item in item_dict` to see if it exists as a key

Comment: Oh, hold on. I've found another issue, but you've accepted my answer. I don't think my answer can give you the correct output except for the last code block (I can't test) because it's appending the whole dictionary (which is what you did). I wan't to update it... but you've marked it correct. Is it _really_ doing what you want? I suspect it's not for the first 2 approaches; you're not under obligation to accept an answer if it doesn't fix your issue

Comment: I've tried it with the first 2 approaches without success. But the last approache gave me the correct output. So i would continue to write my programm with this approach or do you recommend to maintain the approach with the dictionary?

Comment: Ok, perfect, then I'll fix the first 2 approaches to bring them all in line. I would personally use the last approach I gave, in the end, but you'll need to understand what it's doing. I tried to present it as a sequence of changes for you to build up to. I'll edit it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three main issues with your code:

1. You use `if item == item_dict.keys():` which almost certainly cannot be `True`. You're comparing for equality against a `dict_keys` object. Instead, to check for membership in a dictionary, you should just test whether the key is `in` the dictionary
2. Even if you fix the issue in (1), you append *the whole dictionary* to your list in `date_list.append(item_dict)`. Instead, you need to use the key to get at the value.
3. You're using pandas to read a CSV and then cumbersomely converting it into a dict. A lot of answers suggest Pandas for this kind of work, which seems excessive at times, but you should do it idiomatically if you are going to use pandas and not the `csv` library

This should do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

## Create new list with data inside .csv

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";")

item_dict = pd.Series(df['Date'].values, index=df['Items']).to_dict()

## Creating a list with dates from dictionary

date_list = []

for item in items_list_sold: # Use "in" to check for membership
    if item in item_dict:
        date_list.append(item_dict[item]) # You need to use "item" as a key to get at the date value
```

Which could be further compressed with a *list comprehension* to:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";")

item_dict = pd.Series(df['Date'].values, index=df['Items']).to_dict()

date_list = [item_dict[thing] for thing in items_list_sold if thing in item_dict] # Shorter, but getting harder to read now, as-of the edit
```

I've used `"thing"` because `"item"` makes it a bit confusing if you're not used to list comprehensions.

Given the realisation in point (2), a cleaner list comprehension *might* be:

```
date_list = [date for item, date in item_dict.items() if item in item_list_sold]
```

And finally, since you're using pandas anyway, you could just use that for the whole thing, which would be the best approach:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";")
date_list = df.loc[df['Items'].isin(item_list_sold), 'Date'].tolist()
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain their reasons so that I can address them?